# Screen recording and live streaming (Windows DXGI) - C++

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, streaming, h.264, rtmp

I am using the Desktop Duplication API in Windows to obtain images of the screen. I know to obtain the bitmap image of the screen by using the API but I am stuck after this. To stream it to the server I thought of encoding it into H264 and then encoding that again to RTMP and then streaming it to the server. Is there a better and faster way?

I searched many times and most of the answers are using FFmpeg and just finishing the whole task of screen recording to streaming in a single line. Please tell me a way to do this programmatically!!

How do I encode to H264 and then to RTMP? If the video is being double encoded, will this result in a loss of performance in both streaming side and receiving side?

Please point me in the right direction. Any hints or links will be very helpful.

Comment: Did you ever manage to do this? I'm stuck too